# What's the difference between REISUB and a regular reboot?

Tags: magic-sysrq

I know doing REISUB is better than pressing the reset button, but what is the difference between doing this and executing `reboot` through the terminal or rebooting through the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal reboot through GUI or the `reboot` command will stop any running services in the order determined by their dependencies. For services like database engines, doing things in the proper order and waiting for the individual services shut-down procedures to complete before shutting down other things may be very important.

The <kbd>E</kbd> step of Magic SysRQ REISUB will just send a termination signal to all services at once, ignoring their dependencies. So it is very much possible that if service X needs service Y in its regular shutdown process, it may find that Y has already stopped and cannot be used any more, and so service X cannot perform an orderly shutdown and must crash.

Furthermore, the <kbd>I</kbd> step of REISUB will send the equivalent of `kill -9` to all processes except process #1. If you did not wait enough for services that need time for a controlled shutdown after the <kbd>E</kbd> step, this will forcibly stop (i.e. crash) them while their shutdown process is still ongoing. For some services this might not be a problem; for something like a database, it might be very bad.

And if you don't wait enough after the <kbd>S</kbd>ync and <kbd>U</kbd>nmount steps, you might cause the system to <kbd>B</kbd>oot before it has managed to flush all the cached write operations to disk. A journaled filesystem may save you from filesystem corruption, but the cached data will still be lost.

The normal shutdown will handle all these things for you automatically; with SysRq REISUB, you need to understand what the system is doing. If you REISUB a big database server without a very good reason to, a database administrator is going to be very angry. Even if you have a good reason, you might want to wait a few minutes between <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> to give the database a good chance to shut down as cleanly as it can under the circumstances.

But a desktop that was basically only running a web browser before REISUBbing? That's probably not a problem at all. You probably won't even need to pause between the keystrokes.

Also, if your normal shutdown procedure requires *starting* something (e.g. a tool that communicates to a cluster or a monitoring system that this host is being intentionally taken off-line), such steps will be missed by REISUB.